# Ui Router End to End testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-router, end-to-end

I am trying to create an end to end test with an angular app that uses ui router.

What I want it to switch state and have it behave exactly like the "real" running application.

The issue I am having is that the state does get switched, and the state's resolve seems to get resolved correctly, but the state's controller doesn't get instantiated.

For example:

State definition

```
$stateProvider.state('project', {
    controller: 'RootCtrl',
    template: '<div>Empty</div>'
    url: '/',
    resolve {
        anything: function() {console.log('This Gets Called!');}
    }
}
```

Controller

```
controller('RootCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log('Success!');
});
```

Unit Test

```
it('should switch state', function () {
     var app = this.$controller('AppCtrl', {$scope: this.$rootScope.$new()});

     this.$state.go('project');

     this.$httpBackend.flush();
     this.$interval.flush(100);
     this.$rootScope.$digest();
     this.$rootScope.$apply();

    // Controller never instantiated! 
});
```